# TestDFSIO in Hadoop 2.7.2

Tags: hadoop

If I want to run the benchmarking hadoop TestDFSIO application, where is the file or document stored? specifically Hadoop 2.7.2
And file save in Local or HDFS directory?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code [TestDFSIO.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/TestDFSIO.java#L188) the HDFS data is stored in:

```
  private static String getBaseDir(Configuration conf) {
    return conf.get("test.build.data","/benchmarks/TestDFSIO");
  }
```

And the local results are stored in `TestDFSIO_results.log`.

See [Benchmarking and Stress Testing an Hadoop Cluster with TeraSort, TestDFSIO & Co.](https://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/09/benchmarking-and-stress-testing-an-hadoop-cluster-with-terasort-testdfsio-nnbench-mrbench/) for more information.